# Create a dataframe column conditional to the Datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Imagine I have the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({"Date":["10/29/2022", "10/30/2022", "11/5/2022", "11/6/2022"],
      "Values":[1, 6, 8, 12]})
```

I would like to create a new column with a value that equals to 0 if the row has a date before today and 1 to a date that's still on the future.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['new'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False) # convert to datetime
             .gt(pd.Timestamp('today')) # is the date after today?
             .astype(int)  # result as 0/1
            )
```

Output:

```
         Date  Values  new
0  10/29/2022       1    0
1  10/30/2022       6    0
2   11/5/2022       8    1
3   11/6/2022      12    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["new"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]) > pd.Timestamp.now()).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date  Values  new
0  10/29/2022       1    0
1  10/30/2022       6    0
2   11/5/2022       8    1
3   11/6/2022      12    1
```